# Solidity, compiler version error incompatible

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I know is a typical error but I don't know how to solve it. I have tried to add the compile version in the hardhat config file but it doesn't work.

Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

- contracts/MarketOrder.sol (^0.8.8) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.7.0)

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config

Without adding the 0.7.0:

```
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.7.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol (^0.7.0)
  * @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.7.0)

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/MarketOrder.sol (^0.8.8) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.7.0)

These files and its dependencies cannot be compiled with your config. This can happen because they have incompatible Solidity pragmas, or don't match any of your configured Solidity compilers.

  * @uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
```

Comment: The code works fine in remix and sends no dployment version error. i really don't know what is going on with hardhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the hardhat.config file you can add multiple compiler versions, find the snippet similar to and add the compiler version which is required.

```
solidity: {
   compilers: [
     {
        version: "0.8.8",
      },
      {
         version: "0.7.0",
      },
     ],
 }
```

Comment: When I add the version 0.7.0 It shows me the error written above. Can you see any other mistake? Cause adding the version to the hardhat.config doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I added a second error that it is showing when the 0.7.0 version is not added to the hardhat.config. Can you see another posible error??

Comment: delete the node @openzeppelin from node modules and reinstall it. cauz I have everything 0.8 plus in my nodemodules.

Comment: please thumbs up the answer, it will give me some points.

Comment: Already voted for a usefull comment, how can I thumb up tha correct answer?

Comment: I could accept as aswer solved the one above with the code but it was not at all the right one that solved the problem